# Hive create table ignoring 'bytes' type from protobuf

Tags: hive, protocol-buffers

I am having an issue with a protobuf that I am using to create a table.

I have a .proto file with 2 fields in a structure. Hive seems to use only 1 field (EMetaData) and ignores the 'bytes' type field in the table.

```
message EE {
 required EMetaData header = 1;
 optional bytes cl = 2;
}

message EMetaData {
 required uint32 version = 1;
 optional string root_pid = 2;
}
```

The table is created like this in Hive.

```
Hive>desc pbtest2;

OK
key     struct<header:struct<rootpid:string,version:int>>  from deserializer
value   struct<header:struct<rootpid:string,version:int>>  from deserializer
```

Below is my create table statement.

```
create table pbtest2 row format serde 'MyProtobufDeserializer' with serdeproperties ('KEY_SERIALIZE_CLASS'='CEMessages$EE','VALUE_SERIALIZE_CLASS'='CEMessages$EE') stored as inputformat 'MyInputFormat' outputformat 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveSequenceFileOutputFormat'
```

The bytes type cl field is not present in the table. Not sure what the problem is. 
Has anyone run into this issue ? Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out that my SerDe needed some changes. It was not handling 'bytes' type from the .proto file.  After handling that I am able to see the 'binary' type field created for the table.